# Loading JWplayer embed code from database collection into a page template in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, jwplayer

Hello I'm new to meteor and programming in general.

I am trying to have my page load the JWPlayer video embed code dynamically from the database collection.  Since I have over 100 videos being made for this app/site I figured this would be the easiest way.  *Please let me know if there is a better way to do this!!*

The issue it seems is the javascript embed code from the database is loading before the page and as such is not getting executed.  Here is my code.

Template code:

```
<template name="videos">
        {{{viddiv}}}
   <script type='text/javascript'>
        {{{vidscrip}}}
  </script>
</template>
```

The code from the database collection (it's been properly escaped so it's kinda crazy):

```
vids.insert ({
    _id: "1",
    viddiv: '<div id=\'player64I7ulrK\'><\/div>',
    vidscrip: "jwplayer(\'player64I7ulrK\').setup({\r\n
               playlist: \'\/\/jwpsrv.com\/feed\/64I7ulrK.rss\',\r\n        
               width: \'100%\',\r\n        
               aspectratio: \'16:9\'\r\n    
               });"
});
```

When I launch my app and view the page I can see that the everything is there and looks good.  But the script isn't executing.

```
<div id="player64I7ulrK"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   jwplayer('player64I7ulrK').setup({
      playlist: '//jwpsrv.com/feed/64I7ulrK.rss',
      width: '100%',
      aspectratio: '16:9'
   });
</script>
```

And here is the route I am using to render the view (correct terminology?).

```
Router.map(function() {
   this.route('videos', {
    path: '/videos/:_id',
    data: function() {return vids.findOne(this.params._id); }
   });

});
```

I've played with `Template.videos.rendered` and added a separate js file with the embed code in it.  This did work, however I'm not sure how to load the code into this js file dynamically form the database collection.  Which means I would have to hard code each embed =(

Here is the link to my git repository if you would like to look at it!
https://github.com/jacksonvoice/VCU.git

Any help would be great!  I'm kind of stuck on this one and need some help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are new to meteor then I recommend to watch [EventedMind](https://www.eventedmind.com/) screencasts and read [DiscoverMeteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) book.

Comment: I am currently doing both of those things!

Comment: Do you have an example link of where you are running the player on your website?

Answer (score 1):

Embedding js code in db as escaped string is **bad idea** as it is not easy to manage, change, use. 
Instead I would refactor your code a little bit:

```
vids.insert({
   url:'//jwpsrv.com/feed/64I7ulrK.rss',
   width:'100%',
   aspectratio:'16:9',
   divSelector:'64I7ulrK'
})
```

Videos.html:

```
<template name="videos">
  <div class="{{divSelector}}"></div>
</template>
```

Videos.js :

```
   Template.videos.rendered = function () {
      jwplayer(this.data.divSelector).setup({
         playlist    : this.data.url,
         width       : this.data.width,
         aspectratio : this.data.aspectratio
      });
   };
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code and reset the database but I'm getting this error: `Exception from Deps afterFlush function function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'divSelector' of undefined
    at Object.Template.videos.rendered (http://localhost:3000/client/videos.js?c09c8c2fd20195c089aeb729fafd346c8690c52f:2:25)`  Does that mean that `this` is not defined?

Comment: Please commit your changes and push to github repo (https://github.com/jacksonvoice/VCU.git), so I can see it and test.

Comment: @Jacksonvoice I have forked your repo : https://github.com/parhelium/VCU and put some fixes.

Comment: I make sure data is delivered to Template.videos.rendered but the problem right now is with jwplayer. It looks it is not properly included as it contains only function **registerPlugins**.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code but it's still not working.  Is there a CDN or another way I should stream my video that you recommend?  I don't have to use JWplayer.

Comment: Also when you say *not properly included as it contains only function registerPlugins*  I don't know what that means =(

Comment: You can use html5 video tag. See html source of EventedMind site.

Comment: Try manually add jwplayer to body tag. Open console and type : "var p = jwplayer('body'); console.log(p)"