# Best way to stream a video per page/template view in meteor.js

Tags: video, meteor, cdn

I'm new to meteor and trying to setup an educational video site.  I have many videos that will be streamed one per page to members.

Originally I was using jwplayer as the CDN and using the supplied embed code from JWPlayer website:

shown here:

```
<div id='player64I7ulrK'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('player64I7ulrK').setup({
    playlist: '//jwpsrv.com/feed/64I7ulrK.rss',
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: '16:9'
});
```

My original thought was to load the embed code (for the JWPlayer) into a database collection then server a template view per collection _id.  Although I did get this to happen the script wasn't executing, see: [Loading JWplayer embed code from database collection into a page template in meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169135/loading-jwplayer-embed-code-from-database-collection-into-a-page-template-in-met)

Anyway currently it looks like getting this to work with JWPlayer is a pain.  There has to be a straight forward way to accomplish this right?

So my main questions is this, what is the best way to serve streaming video from a CDN in meteor?  Also, What CDN should I use?  Finally, how would you go about dynamically loading this streamed video into a meteor template as to allow a separate view per video?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: This question is a little too broad, but I'll help narrow your focus. What devices do you need to support? Do you actually need a packaged player or can you just use the [video element](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html)?

Comment: It will most likely be desktop.  I could use the video element but I wanted to use a CDN as this will be used by people in many locations.

Comment: Using a CDN is pretty easy. Are you willing/able to have both an mp4 and a webm version of your videos? Are you okay with supporting only modern browsers, or do you need this to work with < IE9?